# Can I use the Google Map Platform API through service account authentication?

Tags: go, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I want to use Google Map Platform API as authentication for authorized service accounts, but the document only says authentication through API keys. I want to know if you are supporting authentication using a service account.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

I looked up the documents about the certification of use of the Google map platform. Since we are developing using Golang, we checked the authentication methods of the package below.

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-go

However, there was no content about authentication using a service account anywhere. I want an answer to whether authentication using a service account is possible or not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While I'm not sure if Golang supports service account authentication, have you seen this doc? https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/ The link you provided seems to be for Maps Javascript which is not what Golang uses I believe.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.